# Creating Custom Actions for Admin Panel sets displayed values to (None)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on creating some custom actions to perform on my data from the django admin panel. I have defined the actions in models.py like so:

```
EX_MODERATION_CHOICES = (
('c', 'Check'),
('d', 'Display'),
('p', 'Pending'), )
```

and added the following to the appropriate model field:

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    ...
    ex_moderationstatus = models.CharField(db_column='EX_ModerationStatus', max_length=1, choices=EX_MODERATION_CHOICES)
```

When I hit the admin panel and check out the data, it displays with the values set to `(None)`. When selecting a specific id I can see that the field to edit is a dropdown menu with my EX_MODERATION_CHOICES as options. I believe that the issue lies here, just not clear on a solution.

If I remove the choices field from the column it displays as I expect with the proper value from the DB like `Display`. Take a look at the pics if you would like. I basically followed the docs word for word and am wondering if anyone has any insights as to what I am missing.

[image: Data Display as None]

[image: Proper Data Display]

I registered the actions in admin.py like so:

```
def make_moderation_status_pending(self, request, queryset):
    rows_updated = queryset.update(ex_moderationstatus='p')

    if rows_updated == 1:
        message_bit = "1 Experience was"
    else:
        message_bit = "%s Experiences were" % rows_updated
    self.message_user(request, "%s successfully marked as Pending." % message_bit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in your database is incosistent with the choices. If you remove the choices field it should show the first strings in the choices iterable - it should show "d" and not "Display". The first element ist what is stored in the database ([docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices))

So either you change the choices list to:

```
EX_MODERATION_CHOICES = (
('Check', 'Check'),
('Display', 'Display'),
('Pending', 'Pending'), )
```

Note that "Deleted" choice is missing in this list.

Or you change the data in the database to the values "d" etc.

Comment: Got it, I have changed the values as suggested and now it behaves as expected. Thanks!